# LNK2005 ... already defined in ... .obj

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I'm beginner C++ programmer, and I have no idea how to fix this code. I found the reason of problem on Stack OverFlow, but I didn't find the solution for my case.

**Error list**

```
    LNK2005 "int X::var" (?var@X@@3HA) already defined in HeaderRealiseOne.obj 
    LNK2005 "int Y::var" (?var@Y@@3HA) already defined in HeaderRealiseOne.obj 
    LNK2005 "int Z::var" (?var@Z@@3HA) already defined in HeaderRealiseOne.obj 
    LNK1169 one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

**main.cpp**

```
    #include "HeaderInterfaceOne.h"

    int main()
    {
        X::var = 7;
        X::print();

        using namespace Y;

        var = 9;
        print();

        {
            using Z::var;
            using Z::print;

            var = 11;
            print();
        }

        print();

        X::print();

        cout << endl;

        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

**HeaderInterfaceOne.h**

```
    #pragma once

    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    namespace X
    {
        int var;
        void print();
    }

    namespace Y
    {
        int var;
        void print();
    }

    namespace Z
    {
        int var;
        void print();
    }
```

**HeaderRealiseOne.cpp**

```
    #include "HeaderInterfaceOne.h"

    void X::print() { cout << "X = " << X::var << endl; }
    void Y::print() { cout << "Y = " << Y::var << endl; }
    void Z::print() { cout << "Z = " << Z::var << endl; }
```

At first, I thought I need to add `extern` before `int var` in all namespaces:

```
    namespace X
    {
        extern int var;
        void print();
    }

    namespace Y
    {
        extern int var;
        void print();
    }

    namespace Z
    {
        extern int var;
        void print();
    }
```

but it caused another problem:

```
    LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "int X::var" (?var@X@@3HA)
    LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "int X::var" (?var@X@@3HA)

    LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "int Y::var" (?var@Y@@3HA)
    LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "int Y::var" (?var@Y@@3HA)

    LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "int Z::var" (?var@Z@@3HA)
    LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "int Z::var" (?var@Z@@3HA)

    LNK1120 3 unresolved externals
```

Please, help to fix it.

Thanks!

Comment: Also `using namespace std;` does not belong in a header file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second approach is correct. You just need to define the `extern` variables in a .cpp file.

Adding

```
int X::var = 0;
int Y::var = 0;
int Z::var = 0;
```

to HeaderRealiseOne.cpp will solve the problem.